# Kafka streams interactive query - duplicate windows

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, kafka-interactive-queries

I am trying to query a 30 seconds windowed store like this:

```
ReadOnlyWindowStore<String, Long> queryableStore
...
KeyValueIterator<Windowed<String>, Long> iter = queryableStore.fetch("A", "E", now - (60 * 1000 * 5), now)
```

Is there a scenario in which I get duplicate windows in the output? I was expecting that this returns 50 unique windows at the most (5 keys x 10 windows). What I am observing is that I get more windows than 50 and some of them are duplicates. Duplicates occur towards the last entries in the iterator. Is it recommended to manually remove the duplicates in this case?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe you are hitting this bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7158 ?

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I am hitting that same issue. When is 2.0.1 coming out? Apparently, thats the first GA with this fix?

Comment: There is no release plan for 2.0.1 yet -- 2.1.0 is planed for end of October. Cf https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Future+release+plan